# can't find openjfx after installing it, except with terminal which shows the file name in red

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, openjfx

I wanted to use a specific version of openjfx so to download it I used the command

```
sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

But intellij idea can't seem to find this file so i looked into it and when I searched for the file with the terminal command

```
find /usr -name jfxrt.jar
```

it came up with the location

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

but when I did

```
ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

I got a response of

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 huhti   6  2018 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar -> ../../../../../../share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

But the file location is red and I can't find it by going through my files in intellij. What does this mean?
This isn't an issue with only this version of openjfx. I can't find the file even if I run just

```
sudo apt install openjfx
```

I'm running ubuntu 19.04 if that's of any help.
Edit: Some more info if I click on the file jfxrt.jar through my graphical file manager it comaplains that "This link cannot be used, because its target "../../../../../../share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar" doesn't exist."
And when I made my way to the location that the link links to it ends in a dead ended at /share/java/openjfx where there was a few files. And in past tense, because now that I checked again there was nothing. Umm what. Idk if this helped at all, but hopefully someone could help me soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a massive pain to fix so if anyone else has this problem basically for some reason apt wasn't able to download all of the dependencies and I had to download libopenjfx-java which was found from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/openjfx_8u161-b12-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html so basically just run

```
sudo apt install libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A red directory on the ubuntu os by default insinuates that you are dealing with an archive file, so this would need to be unzipped or decompressed before you can use it. This would explain why the file isn't showing in IntelliJ, IntelliJ won't show files with extensions that are non-compatible for the operation you are attempting.

It might be easier to download the platform from the official openjfx.io download link, then installing the JavaFX Linux SDK manually.

Comment: If i do want to now unarchive the file how would I go about doing that. I'm trying to learn more about linux so it'd be nice to learn how to solve this problem through the terminal. Does it mean that it's archived via any method If i don't know the method it's archived with how would I go about figuring that out.

Comment: tar -xzvf /tmp/file_location.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            - tar is one of the most commonly used decompression commands.

Comment: doesn't work, because it's not a tar.gz file. I think there's another issue entirely, because the file is .jar which is what it should be.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is what was mentioned on this thread here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/713197/why-ls-a-command-showing-file-name-in-red-color. The non-link file archive appears as red.

Comment: Also I apparently need to use javafx 8 on this project, but I can't find that version from the internet.